# Running kubectl in php shell_exec returns and empty list

Tags: php, kubernetes, kubectl, fpm

On my DO server I am trying to run `kubectl get deployments -o=json` in `shell_exec`, but it either returns `null` or an empty list:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "items": [],
    "kind": "List",
    "metadata": {
        "resourceVersion": "",
        "selfLink": ""
    }
}
```

But when I run it locally, it works:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "items": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "apps/v1",
            "kind": "Deployment",
            "metadata": {
                "annotations": {
                    "deployment.kubernetes.io/revision": "1",
                    "kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration": "..."
                },
                "creationTimestamp": "2021-09-23T11:41:11Z",
                "generation": 1,
                "name": "database-1911797883",
                "namespace": "default",
                "resourceVersion": "...",
                "uid": "..."
            },
            "spec": {
                ...
                "replicas": 1,
                "revisionHistoryLimit": 10,
                "selector": {
                    "matchLabels": {
                        "app": "database-1911797883"
                    }
                },
                "template": {
                    "metadata": {
                        "creationTimestamp": null,
                        "labels": {
                            "app": "database-1911797883"
                        }
                    },
                    "spec": {
                        "containers": [
                            {
                                "image": "...",
                                "imagePullPolicy": "Always",
                                "name": "database-1911797883",
                                "resources": {},
                                "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
                                "terminationMessagePolicy": "File"
                            }
                        ],
                        "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst",
                        "restartPolicy": "Always",
                        "schedulerName": "default-scheduler",
                        "securityContext": {},
                        "terminationGracePeriodSeconds": 30
                    }
                }
            },
            "status": {
                "availableReplicas": 1,
                "conditions": [
                    ...
                ],
                "observedGeneration": 1,
                "readyReplicas": 1,
                "replicas": 1,
                "updatedReplicas": 1
            }
        }
    ],
    "kind": "List",
    "metadata": {
        "resourceVersion": "",
        "selfLink": ""
    }
}
```

I know that `shell_exec` is not disabled in php-fpm and `kubectl config view` prints the same values in both `shell_exec` and cli.

I configured to run php-fpm as the same user that executes the command through cli.

Comment: Try changing the command to `kubectl get deployments -n default -o json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` (or whatever `conf` file you have there that you are using for your web) and uncomment `clear_env = no`.

[From the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php):

```
 clear_env bool

    Clear environment in FPM workers. Prevents arbitrary environment
variables from reaching FPM worker processes by clearing the environment
in workers before env vars specified in this pool configuration are added.
Default value: Yes.
```

Hence, setting it to `no` will allow workers to use the environment information leading to expected output.